# AWS API Gateway: Grabbing embedded event variable works in Lambda, does not in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS.
I'm trying to deploy an API based off of a Lambda function. Everything is set up such as the layers, config, code, etc. However, I'm stuck on the last part.
I've tried to look around for a solution, but I can't seem to find anything that works as of yet.

**Problem:**

I have an AWS Lambda function that takes the following event json as input:

```
{
  "params": {
    "color": "Red (Crimson)"
  }
}
```

I access it via `color_name = event["params"].get("color")` in the Lambda function, manipulate it, and it returns what is desired, i.e., a test event was configured and it was successful.

Now, I'd like to make use of this in an API. To do this, I:

- Added a trigger from the Lambda function to an API Gateway
- Created a new API (REST API)
- Selected 'Add'

Next, I:

- Clicked the ANY method from my resources
- Selected method: POST
- Made the same request as before but for the API.

However, when I test it, the response body is just `"'params'"`.

Is there any way I can get it to return what the lambda function does?

I'm not sure what I'm missing! Any answers appreciated.

---

**Things I've tried:**

Lambda function testing:

When I add the event json as above to the raw `aws-proxy` event template, the lambda function works just fine.

However, when testing my Lambda function with just the raw `aws-proxy` event template, the response is the same as above:

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "\"'params'\""
}
```

Function logs:

```
File "/var/task/color_handler.py", line 46, in get_color
    full_color = event["params"].get("color")
KeyError: 'params'
```

This makes me think it is something to do with the `Use Lambda Proxy integration` option, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

The API gateway wraps the POST request body in a larger JSON that includes other information on the request like headers, query string parameters etc. You'll need to extract your request body from this.

The JSON the lambda function receives should look something like [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig/event.json).

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

I've already used an event.json and input it into the request body.
I can see the variable in the "method request body before transformations" in the log.
It's not in the endpoint request body at all, though. All the variables become `null`.